# Actions on Google Fulfillment Response

Tags: php, actions-on-google

When you receive a request, **your fulfillment must return a response**

I have a HTTPS endpoint which receives commands sent thru the google assistant(My Fulfilment URL). But i want to return a text to the user for every request made 
Eg:
          USER REQUEST : "Tell, 'app name' to do blah blah"
           ASSISTANT RESPONSE : "Okay, sure"
  
 
As documented in  this article --> https://developers.google.com/actions/components/fulfillment (RESPONSE FORMAT) , I have coded the json file according to the format said in the above link 
But it says **your fulfillment must return a response**

## RESPONSE.JSON

```
"finalResponse": {
     "richResponse": {
          "items": [
               {
                 "simpleResponse": {
                 "textToSpeech": "sure thing",
                 "displayText": "Sure, thing!"
                  }
           ]
     }
}
```

In my Fulfilment end point i did the above.

## fulfilment.php

```
$file = [
 "expectUserResponse" => false,
 "finalResponse" => [
 "richResponse" => [
  "items" => [
    [
      "simpleResponse" => [
        "textToSpeech" => "Sure thing!",
        "displayText" => "Sure, thing?"
        ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
  ]
];

echo json_encode($file);    
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

How do i return this file in php back to google assistant?
I am using PHP :)

Comment: Make your `$data` variable an associative array. verify the response by visiting the said URL using your browser.

Comment: How do i make it into a associative array? I need the json file in the above format

Comment: Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). yes, `json_encode` will convert an associative array to a json object. Have you checked the response yourself ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters - that isn't valid JSON. Valid JSON would look something like this:

```
{
    "finalResponse": {
        "richResponse": {
            "items": [{
                "simpleResponse": {
                    "textToSpeech": "sure thing",
                    "displayText": "Sure, thing!"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the opening and closing brackets to designate that this is a JSON object. What you're sending is a string that has been encoded as a JSON string. Using PHP, the easiest way to create valid JSON is to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and pass it a nested associative array. So something like this would generate it.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$a = [
  "finalResponse" => [
    "richResponse" => [
      "items" => [
        [
          "simpleResponse" => [
            "textToSpeech" => "Sure thing!",
            "displayText" => "Sure, thing?"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
echo json_encode($a);
```

Note that the `header()` must come before *anything*, even a blank line, has been sent.

However... that might not be your only problem.

This doesn't look like it has all the fields that you should reply. If you're only sending a `finalResponse`, then you probably also need to set `expectUserResponse` to false.

(And are you sure that you want to end the conversation every time?)

Comment: I updated the code with your awnser but the assiastant is still saying 'APP NAME, isnt responding right now, try again soon" Yes, i want to end the conversation just for now for testing purposes.

Comment: Updated answer to include information about header()

Comment: I did that too, same result. I visited the php page and there arent any php errors either. Still i get 'APP NAME, isnt responding right now, try again soon"